# HTTP Plain-text data to array

Tags: ios4, nsstring, nsdictionary

I'm using the iOS device to access data on a local module, and it gets info from http://.../path_to/file.bin, and the response is in plain-text as:

```
[Header]
Version=1
[Data]
SomeData=aValue
StringKey=Value
TimestampKey=DDD:HH:MM:SS
NumberKey=8321
[Blob]
MoreData=moreValues
[EOF]
Lines=11
```

(timestamp only occurs once and is a time from the current time)
I would like to put all of the information in the string above into a `NSDictionary` to be more easily accessible.  Something appearing like:

```
Dictionary (
    Header => Dictionary (
        Version => 1
    )
    Data => Dictionary (
        SomeData => aValue,
        StringKey => anotherValue,
        TimestampKey => "DDD:HH:MM:SS", //(format into NSDate if you like)
        NumberKey => 8321 //(format into int if you like)
    }
    Blob => Dictionary (
        MoreData => moreValues
    )
)
```

So I would enjoy a function that would format the string input into the dictionary output.

Answer (score 0):

two solutions:

- reformat your data (plist or json) to load them with existing frameworks
- write your own parser

[Here's an example on CocoaWithLove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html)